# Stripe keep the current discount of a subscriber

Tags: django, stripe-payments

I am currently working on a django project and I integrated stripe to manage monthly subscriptions and renew automatically. Everything is working fine but a problem persists.

I have a page to change payment information for a subscriber. For the sake of simplicity, when his card is updated, I recreate a new subscription and delete the old one.

If, for example, he has a reduction of 3 months and he has 1 month left, how to take his current reduction voucher and reintegrate it into the new subscription without restarting the period from zero?

here is the subscription creation code, when the user registers for the first time, it integrates the promo code ID if there is one. It works very well :

```
obj_sub_created = stripe.Subscription.create(customer=stripe_customer.id,coupon = discount_code,items=[{"plan": offer.stripe_plan_id
```

when a subscriber changes their credit card, I cancel their subscription and recreate a new one. At this moment of the code, I know if there is a current and valid reduction. So I try this:

```
stripe.Subscription.delete(subscription_id)
obj_sub_created = stripe.Subscription.create(customer=stripe_customer.id,items=[{"coupon": discount}])
```

The discount variable is a copy / paste json of what stripe returns to me. But it does not work.

Would you have a solution to resume a promotion where she was on a new subscription when changing your credit card ?

thank you very much for your answers

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you delete and create the Subscriptions instead of updating the `default_payment_method` on the existing Subscription? https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/update#update_subscription-default_payment_method

Comment: I may have understood mùal but it seems to me that if the card is not changed within a given time, the subscription expires? Or, the unpaid subscriptions are accumulated over the months? In addition I use the 3d secure which leaves 24 hours before being able to pay. Removing and redoing offers easier and clearer management (for me anyway)